# terminal -bash: command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I'm trying to compile a c++ program on the Mac terminal with gcc then the source files path. I've found some short term fixes on the Internet but I want it so it works every time. Also I hardly know anything about the Terminal so can the solution be explained very simply.

`echo $PATH` gives:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:’/usr/local/bin:??
```

/bin/cat ~/.profile prints no such file or directory,

/bin/cat ~/.bash_profile prints:

```
export PATH=’/usr/local/bin:?? 
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
 PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

When I use gcc to compile the program I get "-bash: gcc: command not found"

However if I run the commands

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

…the terminal works. I'd like to know how to make it work without running those commands.

Comment: On my machine running OS X 10.10.5, I find `gcc` at `/usr/bin/gcc`. I do not think you can execute `gcc` until you install Xcode. Your post does not actually ask a question. So what is the exact problem you want solved?

Comment: @BenBeazley Please confirm the modifications made by patrix♦.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing here? Which command are you trying to run in `bash`, which error message do you get?

Comment: Your first PATH variable is messing up your PATH.  Assuming you need /usr/local/bin, just have PATH="/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}" export PATH" in your .bash.profile and go from there.

Comment: The PATH variable is exported with  `export PATH`, but this won't help you if the PATH definition is wrong to start with. It also won't help you if your issue is not PATH related. So please help us help you in describing the problem you are facing with compiling C++ code, which things you've tried already and where you are stuck now.

Comment: Ben, if you wish to comment here, you need to use the same account you used to ask the question, or use the Contact link at the bottom of the page to request account merge.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the file .bash_profile with nano or another appropriate editor:

Replace:

```
export PATH=’/usr/local/bin:?? 
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

by:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH
```

---

Explanation:

The first line of your current .bash_profile

```
export PATH=’/usr/local/bin:??
```

modifies the standard value of $PATH given by */etc/paths* from

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

to `’/usr/local/bin:??` - which is no valid path.

The fourth and fifth line of your current .bash_profile modifies $PATH to

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:’/usr/local/bin:??
```

Since `’/usr/local/bin:?` is no valid path the finally effective PATH is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
```

which completely breaks your standard PATH. You can still execute all executables in the above directories but you can't omit the superior directories (e.g. to execute nano you have to enter `/usr/bin/nano` instead of `nano`).